# Change order total programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, totals, order-totals

I want to change the order total in Magento 2 for pending order programmatically, the change of the total doesn't include the discount and shipment price, for example:

```
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+
|base total|shipment|discount|grand_total|
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+
|   3000   |   50   |  200   |    2850   |
|   1500   |   15   |   0    |    1515   |
|   4500   |   0    |  1200  |    3300   |
|   2800   |   0    |   0    |    2800   |
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

and i want to change it like this:

```
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+
|base total|shipment|discount|grand_total|
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+
|   2900   |   50   |  200   |    2750   |
|   1450   |   15   |   0    |    1465   |
|   4100   |   0    |  1200  |    2900   |
|   2600   |   0    |   0    |    2600   |
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

how can I do this programmatically, and recalculate the order without affecting the discount and the shipment cost?

```
$order = $this->order->create()->load($orderId);
```

Comment: what is difference between table 1 and table 2? You  just changed the value of base total in both table but end result will be same as per base_total. Can you please elaborate more.